# Understanding promises async/await using parseCSV, what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, async-await, callback

I feel like I a missing something fundamental here.  I simply want to ensure "data" holds the parsed data from parseCSV before I continue to clean/edit it.

What am I missing?  I fundamentally understand async / await but I suppose there is something I don't understand when it comes to callbacks and async / await.

```
const csv = require("csv");
const fs = require("fs");

(async function start() {
  const file = importCSV("src/tg.csv");
  const data = await parseCSV(file);
  console.log(await parseCSV(file)); // why does this print a parser and not the parsed data?
})();

function importCSV(path) {
  return fs.readFileSync(path, "utf8");
}

async function parseCSV(file) {
  return await csv.parse(file, { columns: true }, async (err, data) => {
    if (err) return err;
    //console.log(data);
    return data;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not returning the `data`. the `csv.parse` is not a promise so basically the `data` is being returned to the parent function of the anonymous callback function.
Just think of the implementation of a function who uses callback, how do you implement that?

```
const a = (cb) => {
    const data = getdatafromsomewhere();
    cb(data);
}
```

so if your function is not specifically returning to the parent function the returned data is not referenced from anywhere.

So the easiest way would be to promisify the `csv.parse`

```
const util = require('util');
const promiseParse = util. promisify(csv.parse);

function parseCSV(file) {
  return promiseParse(file, { columns: true })
}
```

Comment: There's no point to `.then(data => { return data; })`.  That does nothing.  And, `.catch(err=>console.log(err));` "eats" all errors so parseCSV never rejects with errors.

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah i know my point was to just show the promisify thing. not actual working error handling and stuff. I will edit it in couple of hours.